# Prove this matrix norm inequality

Tags: linear-algebra

> Suppose $A \in GL(n, \mathbb{R})$ and choose $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $\left\|x_0\right\|= 1$, such that $m :=\left\|Ax_0\right\| = \min_{\left\|x\right\|=1}{\left\|Ax\right\|}$ is minimal. Prove that there is no $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $\left\|y\right\|= 1$, such that $\left\|A^{-1}y\right\| > \frac{1}{m}$.

I think I have to show that if there was such an $y$, it would follow that there exists an $x'$, such that $\left\|Ax'\right\| < \left\|Ax_0\right\|$, hence contradicting our assumption that $m$ is minimal.

From what I understand it's probably possible to prove this by using arguments involving the SVD of $A$, but i'm pretty sure there is an (maybe) easier way. However, I don't know how to develop my proof idea further. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Try letting $x'$ be a multiple of $A^{-1} y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're showing here, if you want to use SVD, is that $\sigma_1(A^{-1}) = 1/\sigma_n(A)$.

However, such an approach is not necessary.  Define
$$
x' = \frac{A^{-1}y}{\|A^{-1}y\|}
$$
Note that $\|x'\| = 1$.  How can we use $x'$ to reach the desired contradiction?

Comment: Thanks for your help. By applying $A$ on $x'$ we get that $\left\|Ax'\right\| = (\left\|A^{-1}y\right\|)^{-1} < \sigma$.